# jQuery Ui Slider Handler not getting dragged with mouse in PhoneGap application

Tags: jquery-ui, cordova

I am working on an iPhone Application. I am using PhoneGap in Xcode4 to develop the application and testing it with iPhone simulator 4.3.

My issue is I am using jQuery ui slider in my application to implement audio bar, the slider is moving properly with the audio but I can't drag the slider handle with mouse and when I test the same application with Safari browser it is working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI currently does not support touch events.  I would recommend using jQuery UI Touch Punch to add that functionality - http://touchpunch.furf.com/.